# Proving convergence of a sequence using the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I am given a non-empty set $X$ which is a subset of $\Bbb R^k$ with a function $f:X \to X$. I am required to prove that a sequence $X_n$ in $X$ converges to $f$ given a fixed point on $X$.

**Question**

[image]

**My Solution**

[image]

From the solutions, you can see that I am attempting to use the Squeeze theorem to solve the convergence problem. However, I am not clear as to whether I am doing this correctly or whether the Squeeze theorem is the right tool to use in the first instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a), there is a simpler proof, which doesn't involve the squeeze theorem.

Note $\Vert x_{n+1}-x_n\Vert=\Vert f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})\Vert<\Vert x_n-x_{n-1}\Vert$. This shows the sequence $\Vert x_{n+1}-x_n\Vert$ is decreasing in $\mathbb{R}$, and bounded below by zero, so it has a limit $l$.

Also, if $k>1$ I'm not really sure you can manipulate expressions like $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$ as you could if those were real numbers, or if the expression $x-1$ makes sense.

---

For b), you are trying to prove that the preimage of an open set is open, to conclude $f$ is continuous, right? That is a correct approach. Then again, I at least find it sligthly confusing to manipulate the pre-images of sets to prove continuity. I think it is better to prove it with the $\epsilon-\delta$ notion of continuity, or with convergent sequences, which in this case is straightforward.

A proof with pre-images of open sets is this: Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ an open set. Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ We want to show there is some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B(x,\epsilon)\subset U$. Since $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, $f(x)\in U$. Since $U$ is open there is some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B(f(x),\epsilon)\subset U$. But then
$$
y\in B(x,\epsilon)\Rightarrow \Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert < \Vert x-y\Vert <\epsilon \Rightarrow f(y)\in B(f(x),\epsilon)\subset f^{-1}(U)
$$

This shows there is some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B(x,\epsilon)\subset f^{-1}(U)$